# Is it a good practice to store basket or shopping items in session? (Django)

Tags: python, django, session, shopping-cart

I'm writing an e-commerce system using Django, now I need to create a shopping basket mechanism. 
I use Django session for adding, removing and updating shopping cart but I don't know is it a good practice? or are there any better solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827764/ecommerceshopping-cartwhere-should-i-store-shopping-cart-data-in-session-or/48870801#48870801

Comment: Tnx buddy, after all, I go with ajax approach and update the UI respectively, I think sessions cost server more process.